# Hbase Zookeeper Standalone mode

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper, nosql

I have a setup with hbase deployed in standalone mode. Everything works fine initially but after 30 mins or so my zookeeper service dies. I get this exception:

```
2015-05-05 19:52:06,999 ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper getData failed after 1 attempts
2015-05-05 19:52:06,999 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: clean znode for master0x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to get data of znode /hbase/master
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getDataNoWatch(ZKUtil.java:775)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MasterAddressTracker.deleteIfEquals(MasterAddressTracker.java:251)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZNodeClearer.clear(ZNodeClearer.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:1996)
2015-05-05 19:52:06,999 WARN  [main-SendThread(agalaxy:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2015-05-05 19:52:06,999 ERROR [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: clean znode for master0x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
```

I am pumping stream of continuous data into hbase. I checked zookeeper logs, but much of it is non-readable. I couldn't trace the reason for the service to die off. Can anyone please help. Thanks! Here's my config

```
<configuration>
   <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name>
        <value>localhost:60000</value>
        <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
        <value>60020</value>
        <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///data/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/data/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/data/hbase/tmp</value>
 </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
        <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
            The port at which the clients will connect.
        </description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have found the reason of the problem ? And have you found a solution to it ?

Comment: @Alp: Hey, I don't if I really found what caused this issue. But I have a hunch, I was using hbase's zookeeper and once I had logged in to the Zookeeper CLI: `${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase zkcli` and did `ls /hbase`, `master` was missing in the output. So, that explains why it wasn't able to getdata for that znode. Hope this helps, please share your experience!

Comment: Thanks for your response. My case was not exactly the same. I was just suspicious, and was trying to exhaust all possible leads. In my case, I was given a bunch of put mutations, for which I needed to create tables with column families as I go. System worked for a while but at certain point in time, zookeeper died on me. I spent some time to figure out the reason.I couldn't pin point the issue in a short period of time, but instead, I created all necessary tables upfront and then added mutations. It worked like a charm. I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.port</name>
    <value>localhost:16000</value>
    <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
    <value>16022</value>
    <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///data/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/data//hbase/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
    <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.</description>              
  </property>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).